# How to split a string to get related data JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, drop-down-menu, split

I have string from which I am getting data in array but I am not getting way to get so that I get related data in array like my string is,

```
[{"Class Room": ["Windows",  "Windows1"],  "Staffroom": ["Windows",  "Windows1"]}],  "
```

here i have two dropdowns ,

`"Class Room"`  having two values in dropdown Windows and Windows1

another drodown,

`"Staffroom"`  having two values in dropdown Windows and Windows1

How would i get dropdown related value in array i can use split operation but cant getting logic

Above given string is in list, my code is ,

```
String[] data = list.toString().split(",");
```

But it split in array then I would not have related data

I want it to split in way so that I would get relative `dropdown` data in array,

```
  "Class Room": ["Windows",  "Windows1"], value in aray index 0
   "Staffroom": ["Windows",  "Windows1"]}] value in array index 1
```

String is not fix it is generating on run time number of `dropdown` and values of `dropdown` vary time to time but pattern of string same as mentioned above

Comment: Why `String[] data = list.toString().split(",");` when you can `String[] data = list.toArray();`

Comment: Bohemian would it give me array the same that i need ?

Comment: Is your String is JSON?

Comment: @Pratik it was in JSON i converted it into string

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the UI framework that you are working. If you are using Swings then you have to use ActionListener to display related data. For example

```
private String s1[] = { "None", "J2EE", "DataBase", "Scripting Language",
            "Computer Networks" };

    private String s2[][] = { { "None" }, { "Core Java", "Advanced Java" },
            { "Oracle", "SQL", "SyBase" }, { "Java scripts", "c#", "CGI" },
            { "MCSE", "CCNA", "CCNP", "CCIE" } };
...
skill = new JComboBox(s1);
specificSkill = new JComboBox(s2[0]);
...
skill.addActionListener(new ComboAction());
...
specificSkill.setSelectedIndex(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which can solve your problem as it is tested and verified.

```
String temp = "[{"Class Room": ["Windows",  "Windows1"],  "Staffroom": ["Windows",  "Windows1"]}],";
        String parts[] = temp.split(",");
        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i =i+2) {
            listItems.add(parts[i]+","+parts[i+1]);

        }
```

Or you can use regex to break the string at a particular occurence of a character.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hitest does it work for this particular string or any string in this format because number of dropdown and its value change every time

Comment: It will work for any number of dropdowns as first it will split it up on all the comma(,) and will store every value in the array whose size will be double the number of dropdowns. Say you have 10 dropdowns so you will have array of size 20. After that we add all the inputs by combining them in a pair of two and since we use Arraylist to store the result and arraylist can be extended to any size so you will face no problem even if your input size changes every time. Like in this case arraylist will store 10 String Objects which will be as you need - @user3664724